# Как вызвать модальное окно через jquery вместо alert?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У меня есть форма обратной связи на сайте. При отправке формы появляется `alert`(я хочу его заменить на красивое окно),с сообщением об отправке.

Как вызвать модальное окно через Jquery?

Исходный код такой min.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //E-mail Ajax Send
    $("form").submit(function() { //Change
        var th = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mail.php", //Change
            data: th.serialize()
        }).done(function() {
            alert("Thank you!");
            setTimeout(function() {
                // Done Functions
                th.trigger("reset");
            }, 1000);
        });
        return false;
      });

    });
```

В Html сделал `div` модальное окно с `display:none` с `id="modal"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //E-mail Ajax Send
  $("form").submit(function() { //Change
    var th = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "mail.php", //Change
      data: th.serialize()
    }).done(function() {
      // $('#modal').show() // не так крисво будет
      $('#modal').addClass('active') //в css сделать крисивую стилизацию
      setTimeout(function() {
        // Done Functions
        th.trigger("reset");
      }, 1000);
    });
    return false;
  });

});
```

Css:

```
#modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: .3s;
}
#modal.active {
    z-index: 999;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: .3s;
}
```

При это, надо убрать `disaplay: none`